# Trying to add borders to this range and end on the last row of data. However the borders run to line 2050 or the length of the page

Tags: excel, vba

I have tried using R1C1 format and others to have borders stop at the last line of data in Column A, this will read "Overall - Total".

```
Sub Sumif_BD_Prem_Until_LastRow()

Dim LastRow As Long
Dim wb1 As Workbook


Set wb1 = Workbooks("macro all client v.01.xlsm")

LastRow = wb1.Sheets("CGIBill").Range("A:A").Find("Overall - Total",      SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row

LastRow1 = wb1.Sheets("CGIBill").Range("A:A").Find("Overall - Total").Row

For i = 21 To LastRow

Cells(i, 19) = Application.SumIfs(wb1.Sheets("Detail").Range("T:T"),   w   wb1.Sheets("Detail").Range("K:K"), Cells(i, 3),   wb1.Sheets("Detail").Range("M:M"), Cells(i, 9))

Next

With Sheets("CGIBill").Range("A20:V20" & LastRow1).Borders
       .LineStyle = xlContinuous
       .Weight = xlThin
       .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Change With Sheets("CGIBill").Range("A20:V20" & LastRow1).Borders to With Sheets("CGIBill").Range("A20:V" & LastRow1).Borders

Comment: That works perfectly.  Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: Looking to mark as answered, but dont see the green arrow

Comment: I'll add an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is how/where you're applying the LastRow.  You need to replace the 20 value with whatever you've calculated it as.

So if you change

```
With Sheets("CGIBill").Range("A20:V20" & LastRow1).Borders
```

to

```
With Sheets("CGIBill").Range("A20:V" & LastRow1).Borders
```

You should get your expected results.